# how to exclude escaped characters in split() javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I am looking to ignore the characters inside the square brackets because it matches with my split parameters.

The string that i want to split is

```
var str = "K1.1.[Other] + K1.2A.[tcc + K*-=>]";
var split = str.split(/[+|,|*|/||>|<|=|-]+/);
```

I want the output as `K1.1.[Other], K1.2A.[tcc + K*-=>]`.

But this above code is including the characters inside square brackets which i don't want to consider. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you not split on ` + ` ? Note the space preceding and following the `+`.

Comment: I might have space inside the square brackets also. so that might not work all the time.

Comment: lexical parsing is really bad use case for regexp. can you use one-by-one analysis instead?

Comment: @user3842125 if the single example string you've given isn't an accurate representation of the data you're trying to split, then you're going to have to provide more examples.

Comment: You  have already the answer below, just use your own delimiter set, `/[+,*\/|><=-](?![^\[]*\])/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on the following pattern: `/\+(?![^\[]*\])/`

https://regex101.com/r/NZKaKD/1

Explanation:

`\+` - A literal plus sign

`(?! ... )` - Negative lookahead (don't match the previous character/group if it is followed by the contents of this block)

`[^\[]*` - Any number of non-left-square-brackets

`\]` - A literal right square bracket

Answer (score 1):

split by both plus and braces as well. then go through chunks and join everything between  braces pairs.

But better not to use regexp at all for that.